# SonarQube docker container can't start, elasticsearch issue

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I'm trying to run official SonarQube Docker container locally. I'm using the command provided here: 
https://hub.docker.com/_/sonarqube/

It exits about 1 minute after it was started. Logs are reporting Elasticsearch connectivity issue

```
2017.09.05 08:16:40 INFO  web[][o.e.client.transport] [Edwin Jarvis] failed to connect to node [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9001}], removed from nodes list
org.elasticsearch.transport.ConnectTransportException: [][127.0.0.1:9001] connect_timeout[30s]
.....
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9001
.....
    ... 3 common frames omitted
2017.09.05 08:17:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [web] is stopped
2017.09.05 08:17:10 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
```

Comment: I got the Same Issue :
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
es[][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/opt/sonarqube/data (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [4gb], net total_space [21.5gb], types [ext4]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out SonarQube container didn't have enough resources. I shut down other docker containers and it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the because of the system setting `vm.max_map_count`

the value should be a minimum of 262144. More details in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docker.html#docker-cli-run-prod-mode)

in Linux machine, the configuration can be added in the file `/etc/sysctl.conf`